# Triangles not drawn after hitting home button on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Hello I have recently been playing around with OpenGL ES 1.1 on android ndk and I'm kind of stuck with a problem. Whats happening is that I'm rendering a simple red square on the screen, when I launch the app the square shows up perfectly but when I hit the home button and return to the app the square is not showing up anymore. I tried calling `getError` after calling `glDrawArrays` to see if an error occurred and it always returns `GL_NO_ERROR`. I read in the android site the following:

> There are situations where the EGL rendering context will be lost.
>   This typically happens when device wakes up after going to sleep. When
>   the EGL context is lost, all OpenGL resources (such as textures) that
>   are associated with that context will be automatically deleted. In
>   order to keep rendering correctly, a renderer must recreate any lost
>   resources that it still needs. The onSurfaceCreated(GL10, EGLConfig)
>   method is a convenient place to do this.

What I did was print on log cat every stage of the activity and when hitting the home button and returning to the app, the system is not calling `onSurfaceCreated`. I also tried printing in log cat my vertices just to check that somehow they are getting destroyed and I was just sending wrong values to `glVertexPointer` but it looks like it was ok. Here is the code:

```
    static jint initialize(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint width, jint height){
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);

        glClearColor(100.0f/255.0, 149.0f/255.0f, 237.0/255.0f, 1.0f);

    }

    struct Vertex {
         float Position[2];
         float Texture[4];
    };

    static void gameRun(JNIEnv* evn, jobject obj) {
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

         const Vertex Vertices[] = {
        {{ 0.0f, 100.0f },   { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }},
        {{ 0.0f,  0.0f },    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }},
        {{ 100.0f, 100.0f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }},
        {{ 100.0f,  0.0f },  { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }},
         };

         glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
         glLoadIdentity();

         glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
         glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

         glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &Vertices[0].Position[0]);
         glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &Vertices[0].Texture[0]);

         GLsizei vertexCount = sizeof(Vertices) / sizeof(Vertex);
         glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);

         glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
         glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }
```

**NOTE:** The function `initialize` is called from `onSurfaceCreated` and `gameRun` from `onDrawFrame`.

One thing that struck me odd wast that when running the app again on my phone after a home button, the system would call on the function `onSurfaceChanged` two times. Not sure if it has to do with anything but its just odd.

If anyone could please help me I would be really grateful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after doing some testing and comparing to some sample projects, I noticed a copule of things. In one project when calling glOrthof I would pass a ratio between the width and the height for left and right, and I would pass -1 and 1 for top and botton:

```
float ratio = width / height;
glOrthof(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

And when I hit the home button and then run the app again, I noticed that the square would scale.

In another project I would simply create a projection matrix and then I would set it with glLoadMatrix on my gameRun function:

```
mat4 projection = mat4::Frustum(-2, 2, -h / 2, h / 2, 5, 10);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(projection.Pointer());
```

And when I hit the home button and then run the app again, I saw that this time the square would show up with no problem. I then began to read the documentation of OpenGL ES 1.1 and found the following:

> glOrtho describes a transformation that produces a parallel
>   projection. **The current matrix (see glMatrixMode) is multiplied by
>   this matrix and the result replaces the current matrix ...**

And it suddenly hits me... Because after coming back from the home interrupt, my application is using the previously created context. So what it is actually going on is that when I call `glOrthof` this time the values are multiplied by the ones set before my application was interrupted . This would cause my Ortho to enlarge in a square factor. Making my 100 x 100 square to render really really really small. In order to fix this I just simply added a `glLoadIndentity` before calling `glOrthof`:

```
static jint initialize(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint width, jint height){
   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);

   glClearColor(100.0f/255.0, 149.0f/255.0f, 237.0/255.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

This works because `glLoadIdentity` replaces the value that was there before with an identity matrix:

> glLoadIdentity **replaces the current matrix with the identity matrix.**
>   It is semantically equivalent to calling glLoadMatrix with the
>   identity matrix
>
> ( 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 )

And thus fixing the problem!! :D